# Custom back button in Angular with UI-Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using UI-Router and am trying to update a link in my top navigation bar to give users the option to 'go back' - however, not necessarily where they have just come from, but the logical step backwards. Ie if they are in a client edit page, the back button would take them to the clients list, same with tasks, etc.

The navigation bar is part of the 'root' defined state - see ***top-toolbar@root*** below.

```
.state('root', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '',
    views: {
        '@': {
            templateUrl: '../partials/icp_index.html',
            controller: 'AppController as AppCtrl'
        },
        'left-nav@root': {
            templateUrl: '../partials/left-nav.html'
        },
        'right-nav@root': {
            templateUrl: '../partials/right-nav.html'
        },
        'top-toolbar@root': {
            templateUrl: '../partials/toolbar.html'
        }
    }
})
```

In my other states, I am padding a backButton object via the params option.

```
.state('root.tasks.detail', {
    url: '/:taskId/edit',
    views: {
        'content@root': {
            templateUrl: '../partials/edit-task.html',
            controller: 'TaskDetailController as TaskDetailCtrl'
        }
    },
    params: {
        backButton: {
            text: 'Tasks',
            route: 'root.tasks'
        }
    }
})
```

In my app's run method, I call a custom service, as follows:

```
.run(function($rootScope, NavigationService) {
    $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", console.log.bind(console));
    $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function() {
        $rootScope.backButton =  NavigationService.updateBackButton();
    });
})
```

And here is the service:

```
.service('NavigationService', function() {
    this.updateBackButton = function($state) {
        var backButton = $state.params.backButton;
        return backButton;
    }
})
```

And in the toolbar, I use the route property of the backButton object to define the ui-sref as follows:

```
ui-sref="{{ backButton.route }}"
```

However, the backButton object does not seem to update. The service definitely runs each time the state changes - have console logged to check.

Strangely, when browsing to the following state, the code works - but not with any of my other mutliple states:

```
.state('root.clients.dashboard', {
    url: '/:clientId/dashboard',
    views: {
        'content@root': {
            templateUrl: '../partials/client-dashboard.html',
            controller: 'ClientDetailController as ClientDetailCtrl'
        }
    },
    params: {
        backButton: {
            'text' : 'Clients',
            'route' : 'root.clients'
        }
    }
})
```

I appreciate there may be a much better way of doing this, and probably without using $rootScope - the name itself makes me think I should not be changing properties of it!

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In fact there is an easy solution with $rootScope :

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, to, toParams, from, fromParams) {
        $rootScope.previousState = from;
    });
  }]);
```

The rootScope is just the main parent scope so don't be affraid to play with it. You could also do the same thing with a local storage for the previous state

Comment: Thanks @dmcissokho but as I said, I'm not trying to get the previous state, but decide (based on the current state) where the logical step backwards would be an provide that as the back option. That's what the text property is for - so I can clearly inidcate where they'll be taken back to